Why am I getting a "Cannot resolve keyword" Error in DJango when performing a large sum?
I am developing an e-commerce website where only logged-in users can make orders. I want to get the total price for all orders during checkout (i.e., order_price_total), but get an error:
Cannot resolve keyword 'order_price_total' into field. Choices are: delivered, id, order_date, paid, product, product_id, quantity, ready_for_delivery, shipped, user, user_id

Below is an extract of my code (the model and view):
class Product(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Shop, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='meadia/product-image', null=True)
    key_features = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    specifications = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True, blank=True)
    order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    shipped = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ready_for_delivery = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def order_price_total(self):
        if self.paid == False:
            total_price = self.product.current_price * self.quantity
        return (total_price)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.product_name



##VIEW
@login_required(login_url='login')
def orders(request):
    order = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    total_amount = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, paid=False, delivered=False).aggregate(TOTAL = Sum('order_price_total'))['TOTAL'] or 0

    context={
            'order':order,
            'total_amount':total_amount,
        }
    return render(request, 'mainapp/cart.html', context)


Do you know what a QuerySet (and Sum, for that matter) is? Do you know how it is related to the database? How should the database become aware of your python class' method? You can either use db-generated columns (django 5.0+ only) or rewrite order_price_total as a database function.

You can not work with a method or property to aggregate over. You build the item as query, so:
from django.db.models import Case, F, When


@login_required(login_url='login')
def orders(request):
    order = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    total_amount = (
        Order.objects.filter(
            user=request.user, paid=False, delivered=False
        ).aggregate(
            total=Sum(
                Case(
                    When(
                        paid=False,
                        then=F('product__current_price') * F('quantity'),
                    )
                )
            )
        )[
            'total'
        ]
        or 0
    )

    context = {
        'order': order,
        'total_amount': total_amount,
    }
    return render(request, 'mainapp/cart.html', context)
based on the Product model however, there is no .current_price field.

I used annotate and in my case, it worked in just 1 line of code.
Total_price = request.user.order_set.filter(paid=False, 
              delivered=False).annotate(subtotal=F('quantity') * 
              F('product_current_price)).aggregate(total_price=Sum('subtotal', 
              output_field=FloatField()))['total_price'] or 0 


Use Property tag
as bellow
class Order(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, null=True, blank=True)
        order_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    shipped = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ready_for_delivery = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)


    @property
    def order_price_total(self):
        if self.paid == False:
            total_price = self.product.current_price * self.quantity
        return (total_price)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.product_name

In template you can use order.order_price_total

How about to get all order totals for each user? Kindly

total_amount = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, paid=False, delivered=False).aggregate(TOTAL = Sum('order_price_total'))['TOTAL'] or 0
this should work from your code please let me know if it doesnt

It did not work
